# установка Windows 10 c флешки на ssd

Tags: windows, usb, установка, bios, ssd

Записал Iso образ на флешку и записал ее через Microsoft утилиту дома через мой биос в компе все нормально определяет и делает загрузку, а с ноутбука hp250 G8 bios 2.0.2.0 не видит флешку
Uefi boot не определяет не флешку ни внешний жесткий диск в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуй `rufus`.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты проблем:

*1. Проблемы с USB портами*

*2. Файловая система накопителей*

*3. Secure boot установлен True в самих настройках bios*

Перепроверьте usb порты на исправность, проверьте значение secure boot в bios, проверьте сами накопители на исправность, проверьте может ли быть загружен накопитель на другом устройстве (не просто отображаться в списке, а что бы была возможность полноценно загрузится). Попробуйте перезаписать образ с использованием другой утилиты.